# Marginal Predictions / Marginal Effects in R

Tags: r, regression, logistic, stata, marginal-effect

I’m using marginal predictions to derive more interpretable estimates from mixed-effects logistic regressions in R (glmer). I’d like to obtain predictions in a way where the variable of interest remains fixed but the other variables remain at their observed values. In Stata, one can use the “as observed” default function. In R, I’ve found how to run the predictions where the variable of interest remains fixed but the other variables (e.g., household size, age) are held at their mean values. I’d like to run the predictions such that the means of other variables are not used, but their actual values are used in R.

Is there a way to do this in R? The packages available don’t seem to include the model objects belonging to glmer() classes.

Comment: something like https://strengejacke.github.io/ggeffects/reference/ggpredict.html?

Comment: Is it possible to store the Xs you want to vary somewhere else, change the Xs to the values you want, predict, and then restore the Xs?